# C++ Multiset count()

Tags: c++, count, insert, equals, multiset

So the problem is the following, I have a multiset where I use the std::equal_to operator for comparing the elements, but when I use the count() method it says all 4 elements in my multiset are equal_to my counts parameter.

```
std::multiset< std::string, std::equal_to< std::string > > mset;
mset.insert("C++");
mset.insert("SQL");
mset.insert("Jav");
mset.insert("C");

for(std::multiset<std::string>::iterator it = mset.begin(); it != mset.end(); ++it){
std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << mset.count("STR");
```

The output is : 4

If i understand right whats happening is "STR"=="C++"=="SQL"=="Jav"=="C"==true.
And this is what I don't understand.

Thankyou for the help.

Comment: C++ `set` and `multiset` (and `map` and `multimap`) don't take a predicate checking if two elements are **equal**, they take a predicate checking if two elements are **ordered** relative to one another. I.e, `a < b`. It's a tad technical, but see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). This is because these containers store the elements in order. If you are looking for hash containers, they are all the same names prefixed with `unordered_...`, e.g. [`std::unordered_multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multiset).

Answer (score 0):

As BobTFish already said in a comment, the `Compare` type of [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) should return `true` if the first argument is "less" (has to be ordered before) the second argument. The default type is [`std::less<Key>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

Answer (score 0):

For elements stored in `std::multiset` you must define [strict weak ordering relation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) `f(x, y)`. One of the properties of strict weak ordering is Irreflexivity, that is `f(x, x)` must be `false`. This property is violated in your strict weak ordering and you have got some undefined results.

What you probably want is to use `std::unordered_multiset` instead.